# How to share code between project and build definition project in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

If I have written some source code in my build definition project (in /project/src/main/scala) in SBT. Now I want to use these classes also in the project I am building. Is there a best practice? Currently I have created a custom Task that copies the .scala files over.

Comment: Can you back up and explain why you're trying to do that? I don't think it's really possible for anyone to suggest a “best practice” on this unless you tell us more about your goals and your thinking that led you to this point. Essentially, what you're describing doesn't sound like good practice to me at all. But if I understood your goal better, maybe my reaction would change.

Comment: @SethTisue: I have written a Task which serializes a graph of Scala objects using Kryo and writes them as files into the classpath of the project. The graph is based on big XML files and parsing them is something which I don't wanna do at runtime. Now when my application starts, I am deserializing back the object graph from the files which requires access to the class files. Another potential use case is when you have written utility classes in the build definition project that you want to re-use in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make the following work? Put the source code for the classes in question should be part of your project, not part of your build definition; the “task which serializes a graph of Scala objects using Kryo and writes them as files into the classpath of the project” part sounds like a perfect job for `resourceGenerators` (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html). Then the only remaining problem is how to reference the compiled classes from your resource generator. I'm not familiar with Kryo. In order to use it, do you need to have the compiled classes on the classpath at the time your generator is compiled, or do they just need to be on the classpath on runtime? If the latter is sufficient, that's easier. You can get a classloader from the `testLoader in Test` key, load the class and instantiate some objects via reflection, and then call Kryo.

If you really need the compiled classes to be on the classpath when your resource generator is compiled, then you have a chicken and egg problem where the build can't be compiled until the project has been compiled, but of course the project can't be compiled before the build definition has been compiled, either. In that case it seems to me you have no choices other than:

1) the workaround you're already doing ("best practice" in this case would consist of using `sourceGenerators` to copy the sources out of your build definition and into `target/src_managed`)

2) put the classes in question in a separate project and depend on it from both your build and your project. this is the cleanest solution overall, but you might consider it too heavyweight.

Hope this helps. Interested in seeing others' opinions on this, too.

Comment: I followed your second suggestion now. This works quite well.

Answer (score 5):

Those seem like unnecessarily indirect mechanisms.

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "project/src/main"
```

Answer (score 5):

Sharing sourceDirectories as in extempore's answer is the simplest way to go about it, but unfortunately it won't work well with IntelliJ because the project model doesn't allow sharing source roots between multiple modules.

Seth Tisue's approach will work, but requires rebuilding to update sources.

To actually share the sources and have IntelliJ pick up on it directly, you can define a module within the build.

The following approach seems to only work in sbt 1.0+

Create a file `project/metabuild.sbt`:

```
val buildShared = project
val buildRoot = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(buildShared)
```

and in your `build.sbt`:

```
val buildShared = ProjectRef(file("project"), "buildShared")
val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(buildShared)
```

Then put your shared code in `project/buildShared/src/main/scala/` and refresh. Your project will look something like this in IntelliJ:

[image]

Full example project: https://github.com/jastice/shared-build-sources

Comment: Great answer, but in your linked project, the project folder seems to be missing?